# /etc/hosts configuration file is ignored when behind a squid proxy

Tags: mac-osx, squid

I put this in my /etc/hosts file:

```
198.252.206.16  stackoverflowtest.com
```

And when I try `stackoverflowtest.com` in my browser, I get this squid error:

```
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://stackoverflowtest.com/

Unable to determine IP address from host name stackoverflowtest.com

The DNS server returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

Instead of this:

```
Stack exchange
Couldn't find 198.252.206.16
...
```

Why squid breaks the hostfile ? Any workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to update the hosts file on the squid server.  The reason for this is that your browser sends the target URL to the proxy, and does not locally resolve the hostname.

Comment: Is there a way to tell my browser not to send the target url to the proxy and resolve the hostname locally ? Because I have no control over the proxy, and I still want a custom hostfile config.

Comment: No effective way comes to mind.  It may be possible to script a complex local proxy that could rewrite requests to use the IP after resolution while retaining the host: header, but only if SSL is not in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `/etc/hosts` mapping inside of Proxy VM/Server, **not in client laptop/computer**